# How to pass List<Model> from view into Controller

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc

I'm trying to pass a model class of List<> type from a view into a controller action method.

I couldn't find an already built in method from mvc to complete this task, and I am not much familiar with ajax/jquery. Few of the previously posted question doesn't really fit to my needs and couldn't get enough. Any help please.

I've a model class, I am able to populate all the data in a view, then a user will make changes to any of those data and the whole data in being displayed in the table should be send into a controller.

A method in my controller is waiting for List type of Model class.

```
public ActionResult Save(List<MyModel> myModel){
   ...
}
```

How can I send my model class into the method in my controller?

I tried the following js code but not working at all

Here is my Model class

```
public class MyModel
{
    public int spi_id { get; set; }
    public int s_id { get; set; }
    public int st_id { get; set; }
   }
```

Here is my View

```
@model IEnumerable<MyModel>

<form action="@Url.Action("Save", "Home")" method="post">

<table class="table" id="tblIe">
    <tr>
        <th>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.s_id)
        </th>

    </tr>

    @foreach (var item in Model)
    {
        <tr>
            <td>
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.s_id)
            </td>

        </tr>
    }

</table>
<input type="submit" name="send" value="Send" id="btnSend" />
```

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function () {
 $("#btnSend").click(function (e) {
    alert("button click");
    e.preventDefault();

    var model = @Html.Raw(Json.Encode(Model))
    $.ajax({
        type: 'post',
        url: '@Url.Action("Save", "Home")',
        data: JSON.stringify({ myModel: model }),
        contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
        dataType: "json",
        success: function (data) {
            alert(data);
        }
    });
    });
});

</script>
```

Here is my controller

```
[HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Save(List<MyModel> myModel)
    {
        _service.SaveMyModel(myModel);

        return View("Index");
    }
```

I need to pass the entire content of this model as a LIST<> into my Save method in my Controller.

Comment: What are the contents of class MyModel?

Comment: They are simple class attributes
id int
school_id int uniruq
style_id int
colour_id int
image_type char(1)
last_update smalldatetime
last_update_by varchar(15)

Comment: You will need to create a view model that contains a list of the MyModel classes and then bind that view model to the view.

Comment: This is exactly what my model class looks, I don't have a problem biding it to my view.All I need is, how to send it back to my controller as a list
    public class MyModel
        {  public int id { get; set; }
        public int school_id { get; set; }
        public int style_id { get; set; }
        public string style_type { get; set; }
        public int colour_id { get; set; }
        public string colour_name { get; set; }
        public ImageType? image_type { get; set; }
        public DateTime? last_update { get; set; }
        public string last_update_by { get; set; } }

Comment: There would be no need to use Javascript, model will be posted back with form. Can you show the html of your table?

Comment: Here is the view
model IEnumerable<MyModel>
<form action="@Url.Action("Save", "Home")" id="form" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <table class="table">
        <tr><th>
                @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.school_id)
            </th>
            ....
        </tr>
        @foreach (var item in Model)
        {
            <tr><td>
                    @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.school_id)
                </td>
                ...
            </tr>
        }
    </table>
    <input type="submit" name="send" value="Send" id="btnSend" />

Comment: as per your table html, there will be only a display of `school_id`, you cant edit anything. any input field missing?

Comment: I have all fields listed the same way as the school id, the comment section here has limited characters and I decided to exclude them (hope it is clear)

Comment: I tried, removing the javascript and but my Save method in my controller is null, and raising an exception

Comment: Please [edit] your question to include code rather than putting it in comments.

Comment: I have now made a proper update to all the necessary code, looking forward for your kind help. Thanks you all

Answer (score 2):

Since you are using a `list`, `foreach` loop won't work to hold and post back the values of model. you would have to use `for` loop with `indexer` to create html elements for all the fields, change your table html as below:

*change your model type to List, indexer won't work with IEnumerable*

Edit: `Html.DisplayFor` will not post back the value, an input field is required to do so. you may use `Html.HiddenFor` for all the fields to achieve that as shown in the code.

```
@model List<MyModel>

<table>
  <tr><th> @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.school_id) </th></tr>
@for(int i = 0; i < Model.Count; i++)
{
  <tr>
        <td>
          @Html.DisplayFor(m=> m[i].school_id)
          @Html.HiddenFor(m=> m[i].school_id)
       </td>
  </tr>
}
</table>
```

and decorate your Save method with `ActionName` and `HttpPost` attributes, action name should be same as given in form definition in the view:

```
[ActionName("Index")]
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Save(List<MyModel> myModel){
   ...
}
```

On button `btnSend` click it will post the model back to Save method, no need of any javascript.

Comment: I am using IEnumerable not List, that's why I used foreach loop. you can now look at the post, I have included all the source code

Comment: `foreach` loop will not help you to post back the model values, make changes as per the solution given in the answer to fix the problem.

Comment: thanks, i changed the foreach loop to forloop, It is only getting the right count of rows but all the fields have null value, and I got null in my database table. Why you think is this?

Comment: you can get values only for fields those have input fields created with on the view. you are using `Html.DisplayFor` for all the fields, it won't post back the values. an input field is required to achieve that.

Comment: So far so good, i am getting values now except for @Html.EnumDropDownListFor which there is no HiddenFor option. I don't want to create a separate input field to copy the value, because it is in the dropdownlist itself where the user will make changes.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/199588/discussion-between-medhanie-w-and-rashid-ali).

Comment: were you able to find the tick sign?

Answer (score 0):

The endpoint expects MyModel object list but you are sending a single MyModel object.
Also make sure you added [HttpPost] attribute on the top of "the public ActionResult Save "

If you can't send the list of object for some reason, you can create a new model which includes a list of MyModel.

Can you try to remove this line "var model = @Html.Raw(Json.Encode(Model))"? and just pass Model instead of model?

Comment: sorry, I missed to include the [HttpPost] but I had it since the beginning. How do I send MyModel object as a List is what I am not clear with.